# Search in SharePoint online with modern experience not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-search

I have a site running in SharePoint online with modern experience. And I need to make sure that the contents of the lists are searchable, when someone search in the default SharePoint search box. To do this I had already changed my Mange Result Source to "Items with same keyword as this item " as default option. I had also changed the " Allow items from this list to appear in search results? " to yes in the Advanced settings of List Search. But still, the search actions doesn't pull the data from my lists.

1. Are there any other things to do? Do I need to create index for each columns to make it available in the search?
2. How can I forcibly say to crawl the data after the indexing?

Note: Please be noted that, I am a newbie in SharePoint.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a few hours, I was able to fix the issue I was having with my `SharePoint` site. Luckily I had another site where the search was working as expected, so I did a comparison with that site, and found out that, some settings are enabled in the working site.

Go to your site settings and click on `Site Collection Features` under `Site Collection Administration`.

[image]

And activate `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` option.

[image]

Now go back to your Site Settings and click on `Manage site features` under Site Actions.

[image]

Now activate the `SharePoint Server Publishing` option.

[image]

Please make sure that you are enabling the settings from site collection feature first as it is a dependency of the other settings.

After I did this change, the search is working fine with my list data. I am not even sure whether this is a bug in SharePoint, and what relation search has with this settings, as I am pure newbie in SharePoint.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to WAIT for some HOURS or DAYS for proper re-indexing. This usually happen when you just add the user to the list or document library. I hope this helps?